# How can I get the Jquery change function to ignore the first occurrence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a simple Jquery script which uses an auto complete to check and uncheck check-boxes based on what value the user selects.It is working for the most part,however when the user puts in the first value,the .change event is fired.How do I get Jquery to ignore the first occurrence of a value put into the textbox?

```
 $(function () {
    var checkboxval;
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC",
        "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang",
        "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp",
        "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var txtbx1 = (ui.item.value);
            $("#tags").val(txtbx1);
            var tags = $("#tags").val(txtbx1);
            //var checkboxval = "";
            checkboxval = tags.val();
            $("#" + checkboxval + "").prop("checked", true);

        },
        change: function () {
            alert("changed detected");
            $("#" + checkboxval + "").prop("checked", false);


        }
    });
   });
```

Here is the link to my jsfiddle script http://jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/23/
Please excuse my code,I am still learning to programme so it might not be best practice.Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Laurie

Answer (score 0):

Laurie are you sure that you just want to ignore first press ?:) if its because you dont want to autocomplete on a string with one letter then put in a length check instead :)

```
if(x.length > 1)
execute
```

Comment: I don't think I explained what I am trying to do properly.I want to uncheck the check-box when a user changes a value in the text-box.The problem is that as soon as I enter a value into the textbox,it's seen as a change which causes the check-box to be immediately unchecked.
I know I'm probably going about it the wrong way so any tips are very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something such as this, with a closure, and then track whether or not that function has been executed.

```
change: function () {
    var executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (executed) {
            alert("changed detected");
            $("#" + checkboxval + "").prop("checked", false);
        }
        executed = true;
    }
}()
```

Comment: Can I ask why you ended the function with ()?

Comment: @Sumit that causes the function to execute immediately, and in doing such, returns the inner function. The end result is that `change:` holds the result of the function, not the function itself.

Comment: Thanks @Robert.I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `minLength` property as described in the [widget docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength)

IE,

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  ...

  minLength : 1, //or however many character inputs you want before firing the search
  ...

});
```